# Llamar a botones desde su Id

Tags: android

Estoy creando una app donde al hacer click en la pantalla se cree automáticamente un `ImageView` y así crear varios `ImageView` y que a cada uno se le asigne un id.

Lo que no puedo realizar es como obtener el id de un `ImageView` anteriormente creado cuando le doy clic. Lo que me sale es siempre el ultimo id creado cuando presiono en cualquier `ImageView`.

Muchas gracias

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView imagen;
int i=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    int x=(int)event.getX();
    int y=(int)event.getY();
    switch (event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            i++;
            FrameLayout layout =(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear);
            imagen = new ImageView(this);
            imagen.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.cruz);
            imagen.setId(i);
            imagen.setX(x);
            imagen.setY(y);
            imagen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Muestra el id del boton presionado"+imagen.getId(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              //Aqui el Toast no me muestra el id que quiero, sino me muestra el id del ultimo boton creado  
            }
            });
            layout.addView(imagen);
            Log.e("Valor x=",String.valueOf(x));
            Log.e("Valor y=",String.valueOf(y));
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Al crear una nueva instancia de imagen , al tratar de obtener el id de esta vista, siempre será el de la última instancia

```
...
 imagen = new ImageView(this);
            imagen.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.cruz);
            imagen.setId(i);
...
...
```

Lo que tienes que realizar es obtener el id de la vista que esta siendo pulsada, esta vista esta indicada precisamente por el mismo `OnClickListener` en su método `onClick(View vista)` :

```
            imagen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View vista) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Muestra el id del boton presionado "+ vista.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
```

de esta forma obtendrás sin problema el id de la vista que esta siendo pulsada.

Answer (score 1):

Por un lado, el id deberías crearlo con `View.generateViewId()` en lugar de usar un contador iniciado en 0. Este método asegura que el id sea único.

El motivo por el que te sale el último es porque estás mostrando el `id` de `imagen` en lugar de el de `v`.

`imagen` quedó seteado al último `ImageView` que creaste.

En el método `onClick`, el `View` sobre el que se hizo click es el pasado por parámetro (`v`).

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
               "Muestra el id del boton presionado"+v.getId(),
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
.show();
```